# How to create a mock redux store until the backend/apis are ready?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

React newbie here, I am using a create-react-app and have no api/backend. For a quick start I want to create some 'mock' store data until the backend is ready. I was thinking to create some reducers which return mockdata from a json file. Then create some selectors to return this data in connected components. Is this the right approach or are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I typically just return static data from the actions, so for example if I was using a thunk:

```
export const addTodo = ({ title, userId }) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(addTodoSuccess([ADD_STATIC_DATA_HERE]));
  };
};
```

that way once you have the API set up all you have to do is write the actual request code.